# Error while installing app

Tags: root-access

Received error of "Your device is rooted, You have been denied access", while installing my co's email software developed for android phone, the same application was working in other phones (Samsung , nexus 4 & 5, HTC etc), can anyone suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: Contact your company's IT department? Rooting is a security risk, and I'm sure they are just doing this to prevent propagation of malware through your device to the company system. Your other devices may not have made the rooted condition clear.

Answer (score 0):

Most organizations don't want to allow use of company software on rooted device as it is considered undesirable for following reasons:

`Warranty` – Some manufacturers assert that rooting voids your device’s warranty. However, rooting will not actually damage your hardware.

`Security` – There are some security issues, like Google Wallet, in particular, has a vulnerability on rooted devices that could allow other apps to access your PIN and other wallet information.  Google Wallet displays a warning message if you run it on a rooted device.

`Bricking` – Rooting a device is a very safe process. However, there’s always some danger of “bricking” a device when you go outside the normal parameters and hack around with it — particularly if you’re trying to root a device or operating system version not supported by a tool. “Bricking” refers to breaking the device, making it about as useful as a brick. When you root, jailbreak, or install a custom ROM, or otherwise hack around, you do so at your own risk. It’s a good idea to do a little bit of research first and see if other people report success rooting your device.

AFAIK, you have 2 choices

1.You need non-rooted device to install your company's proprietary software 
2. you may reach to IT Dept. of your company and request them to allow installing  company's proprietary software on ROOT-ed device. They need to disable the checking of rooted/non-rooted device while installing the software.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will check with IT dept. to allow installing on rooted device

Comment: @sanjaymalviya. Sure. In case if the mentioned answer solved your issue, ACCEPT it as Answer so that others too can benefit from it.